# Parsing data from getTransacion

Tags: web3.js, transactions

I using getTransaction for getting information about transaction.
In response exists data, for example

```
"instructions":
            [
                {
                    "accounts":
                    [
                        1,
                        2
                    ],
                    "data": "11114hL2nVLB9uUbgqq47GSmis2baya74D3p9Bo1y7dLRH1GvqmRuo44Z3ZSZERJm52Fq1",
                    "programIdIndex": 3
                },
                {
                    "accounts":
                    [
                        2,
                        8
                    ],
                    "data": "1111gRTNr8uBbXweSEP3MPGkSeUqXdFrStZa6uRpFoYNKYpTzDaExm934JYRstSc4CZVBBnysJ8hgQs55CUi2an3LuXSZiqiFi2j3jJjHzmwXz1pbvkj6SzJLPRJCNSJG5p4fsa9DoFtonoaQXBp7r1WxKM8D",
                    "programIdIndex": 5
                },
                {
                    "accounts":
                    [
                        2,
                        4,
                        7,
                        9,
                        6,
                        1
                    ],
                    "data": "3xyZh",
                    "programIdIndex": 5
                }
            ],
```

How to decode data information transaction info?
(this "data": "11114hL2nVLB9uUbgqq47GSmis2baya74D3p9Bo1y7dLRH1GvqmRuo44Z3ZSZERJm52Fq1")

By some reason I want to use getTransaction, one of service return result of getTransaction, and I dont want call getParsedTranstion because it was 2 calls: getTransaction and getPrasedTransaciton

Answer (score 1):

Try getParsedTransaction instead of getTransaction. This should get you what you need.

Comment: By some reason I want to use getTransaction, one of service return result of getTransaction, and I dont want call getParsedTranstion because it was 2 calls: getTransaction and getPrasedTransaciton